# How do I add a class to the <html> element without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, class

How do I add the class name "foo" to the root `<html>` element **without** using jQuery (or a similar library)?

Comment: So many duplicates...

Comment: @CoryMawhorter [Manipulating classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript/196038#196038), [grabbing the html element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362907/how-can-i-reference-the-html-elements-corresponding-dom-object/9362944#9362944)

Answer (score 64):

[You can use](http://caniuse.com/classlist) the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) to access an element's list of classes.

```
document.documentElement.classList.add('my-awesome-class');

document.documentElement.classList.remove('my-awesome-class');

document.documentElement.classList.contains('my-awesome-class');
```

Comment: Use with caution, classList partially supports explorer browsers:
http://caniuse.com/#search=classList

Answer (score 61):

Just get the element and append to the list of classes.

```
document.documentElement.className += " foo";
```

Comment: Thank you! It's crazy how you can do so much stuff with jQuery without knowing anything about basic JavaScript… Sorry if this had been asked a million times before, I only managed to find jQuery-based solutions.

Comment: When I use the `-=` operator in the same way to remove a class, I get a `NaN` in the class name, instead of nothing (JS auto-converts to numbers when using `+` and `-` operators?). Of course, if you have just one class, you can simply do `= "";` to remove it, but [the answer by Olivér Kovács](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22224493/1765386) is the best in my case.

Comment: @Anderson In JS when you use `+=` it concatenates the two strings `document.documentElement.className` and `" foo"` but there is no `-` operator for strings in JavaScript. As a result, the interpreter implicitly converts the strings `document.documentElement.className` and `" foo"` to numbers which results in `NaN`s. The result of `NaN - NaN` is `NaN`.  You can see the same result by doing: `"hello" - "foo"` in a Chrome console.

Comment: a simple change to ensure it's always cleanly added to is to use " foo " with spaces before AND after, so if others end up doing it in a bad way, your class is still good.

Answer (score 5):

```
AddClass(document.documentElement, 'my-awesome-class', true); //add
AddClass(document.documentElement, 'my-awesome-class', false); //remove

function AddClass(o,c,bAdd){
    var list = o.className.split(" ");
    if (list.indexOf(c)!==-1){
        if (!bAdd) delete list[list.indexOf(c)];
    }else{
        if (bAdd) list[list.length] = c;
    }
    o.className = list.join(" ");
}
```