# How can I reference the <HTML> element's corresponding DOM object?

Tags: javascript, html

This is how you access the `<body>` element to set a background style:

```
document.body.style.background = '';
```

But how can I access the `<html>` element in a similar manner?  The following doesn't work:

```
document.html.style.background = '';
```

Comment: May I ask why you've set a background on the HTML tag? Does it even display?

Comment: It works... http://jsfiddle.net/aEHdw/

Comment: @Grim [Here you go...](http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php?pid=47)

Comment: You know, I've done that myself now I think about it - to stop Chrome from rending the bottom of short pages as grey. :facepalm:

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `<html>` element can be referred through the [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement) property. In general, the root element of any document can be referred through `.documentElement`.

```
document.documentElement.style.background = '';
```

Note: `.style.background` returns the value for `background` as an **inline style** property. That is, defined using `<html style="background:..">`. If you want to get the calculated style property, use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle):

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
var bgColor = style.backgroundColor;
```

Comment: Just curious, do you know why they would call it documentElement instead of document.html? It's really counter-intuitive IMO.

Comment: Possibly because all documents (XML, SVG,HTML, ...) have a root, and "html" would be very specific to (X)HTML documents.

Answer (score 9):

The root element (`<html>`) can be found in `document.documentElement`, not `document.html`.

This is because `documentElement` is standard DOM and not an HTML specific extension.

Answer (score 0):

Why too set the style on the HTML , do use body tag for any styling ..

to change the background applied on html you have to get to the root of the page

using document.documentElement can do

Use this

```
document.documentElement.style.background = '';
```