# Add CSS class to past events in simple HTML event listing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a static event listing in HTML where I would like to add a CSS class to past and current events dynamically using javascript.

Each event listed will need to display either a single date or a date range, therefore parsing the date (I'm thinking) will need to be done using a data-* attribute—something which I've never worked with before in this sense.

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="events-list-wrapper">
  <div class="event">
    <p class="date" data-date="21-01-2017"><span>Jan</span> 17-21</p>
    <h3>Event Title</h3> ...
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <p class="date" data-date="29-08-2017"><span>Aug</span> 29</p>
    <h3>Event Title</h3> ...
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <p class="date" data-date="12-09-2017"><span>Sept</span> 10-12</p>
    <h3>Event Title</h3> ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle I've been working with, <strike>https://jsfiddle.net/t2v21oh6/1/</strike> edit: https://jsfiddle.net/t2v21oh6/4/. I'm not that strong with javascript, and my code isn't working. Not sure why.

Comment: You can do that either with a library such as JQuery or either through plain JS code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388626/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-the-html-element-without-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `if {} else {}` statement and the [`now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) static method from [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get today's time in seconds.

> The Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

See code below:

```js
let today = Date.now()

$('div.event').each(function() {

  let div = $(this);
  let divDate = Date.parse($('.date', this).text());

  if (divDate < today) {
    div.addClass('past');
  } else {
    div.addClass('today');
  }

});
```

```css
.past {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.today {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="events-list-wrapper">
  <div class="event">
    <p class="date"><span>Jan</span> 17-17</p>
    <h3>Event Title</h3> ...
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <p class="date"><span>Aug</span> 30-17</p>
    <h3>Event Title</h3> ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, but the date parsing isn't ideal. Some dates might span multiple days, so the date won't always be written Month DD-YY. Perhaps I need to parse the date from somewhere else, such as a data-* attribute?

Comment: @Leah it is unclear what you are asking for, edit your question so I can help you out.